Problem after installing ibus-avro

Accoding to the result, How ti install avro on linux i had tried sudo apt install ibus-avro and restart the system.
But the problem arises now. I can't login anymore. Even a new kind of login interface have come that i never seen before.
Here, there are no button to enter or if i press enter on keyboard it not changing anything.
I hope most of the thing i clearly presented. I apologize if anything wrong to present the problem.
I`m using Ubuntu 23 & now using terminal on recovery mode, i deleted ibus-avro but it didn't fixed my problem yet.

There is no Ubuntu 23, and any release from 2023 (23.04 & 23.10) are past END OF LIFE thus off-topic here unless the question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Sorry but Ubuntu 23 has been End of life since July 11, 2024 and is off topic here. Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

FYI:  Your picture login looks normal to me; okay I don't know what release you're using (given what you provided was invalid or at least incomplete), but DM theme changes are usually the result of prior command/changes made by a user with sudo rights. An ability to login (login loop) can be for many reasons (eg. lack of space in $HOME), but text terminal logins often proceed.  If you need help, please be clear & specific with details.

What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Open a virtual terminal using ctrl + alt + f3 and then run the command sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop^.
